# Section Element needs to be closed before the another section element (docbook to dita)

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd, docbook, dita

My input file is docbook.xml and my output need to be in DITA with Topic DTD. In the Topic DTD, the 2nd level section element not allowing inside the 1st level section element.
Here my Input xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE book
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook V5.0//EN" "http://docbook.org/xml/5.0/dtd/docbook.dtd">
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"><article><info><bibliomisc role="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</bibliomisc><issuenum>001</issuenum><date>2016-01-29</date><title>LANDING GEAR</title><subtitle>FUNCTION, DATA
FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</subtitle><bibliomisc role="classification">01</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="responsible.partner.company">F0302</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="originator">F0302</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="applicability">ALL</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="quality.assurance">tabtop</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="skill.level">sk01</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="reason.for.update">First Release</bibliomisc><bibliomisc role="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</bibliomisc></info><?dbfo-need height="2cm"?><section><title>DESCRIPTION</title>
<para>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</para>
<para>Landing gears<itemizedlist>
<listitem><para>Nose Landing Gear</para>
</listitem>
<listitem><para>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</para>
</listitem>
<listitem><para>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</para>
</listitem>
</itemizedlist></para>
<section><title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
<section><para>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</para>
</section></section><section><title>Body Landing Gear</title>
<section><para>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</para>
</section></section></section>
<section><figure xml:id="HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-DTRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D-fig-0001" label="1"><title>Landing gear</title>
<mediaobject><imageobject><imagedata align="center" fileref="ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/></imageobject></mediaobject>
</figure></section>
</article></book>
```

Actual Output Im getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "com.rsicms.rsuite_te:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="title">LANDING GEARLANDING GEAR</title>
   <titlealts>
      <navtitle>FUNCTION, DATA
FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</navtitle>
   </titlealts>
   <prolog>
      <metadata>
         <data-about>
            <data type="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</data>
            <data type="classification">01</data>
            <data type="responsible.partner.company">F0302</data>
            <data type="originator">F0302</data>
            <data type="applicability">ALL</data>
            <data type="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</data>
            <data type="quality.assurance">tabtop</data>
            <data type="skill.level">sk01</data>
            <data type="reason.for.update">First Release</data>
            <data type="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</data>
         </data-about>
         <foreign outputclass="issuenum">001</foreign>
         <unknown outputclass="date">2016-01-29</unknown>
      </metadata>
   </prolog>
   <body>
      <section>
         <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
         <p>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</p>
         <p>Landing gears<ul>
               <li>
                  <p>Nose Landing Gear</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </p>
         <section>
            <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>
            <section>
               <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>
            </section>
         </section>
         <section>
            <title>Body Landing Gear</title>
            <section>
               <p>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</p>
            </section>
         </section>
      </section>
      <section>
         <title>Landing gear</title>
         <image align="center" href="ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/>
      </section>
   </body>
</topic>
```

My xsl file:

```
<xsl:template match="*|text()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="section">
        <section>       
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </section>      
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
        <title>       
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </title>      
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="itemizedlist">
        <ul>       
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </ul>      
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listitem">
        <li>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="figure">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="imagedata">
        <image>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </image>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@fileref">
   <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mediaobject">

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="imageobject">

            <xsl:apply-templates/>

    </xsl:template>
```

Excepted Output xml as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE topic
  PUBLIC "com.rsicms.rsuite_te:doctypes:dita:topic" "topic.dtd">
<topic id="topic_1">
   <title outputclass="title">LANDING GEARLANDING GEAR</title>
   <titlealts>
      <navtitle>FUNCTION, DATA
FOR PLANS AND DESCRIPTION</navtitle>
   </titlealts>
   <prolog>
      <metadata>
         <data-about>
            <data type="data.module.code">HSXWB-A-79-11-11-00A01-000A-D</data>
            <data type="classification">01</data>
            <data type="responsible.partner.company">F0302</data>
            <data type="originator">F0302</data>
            <data type="applicability">ALL</data>
            <data type="data.module.reference.code">TRENTXWB-A-00-00-00-01A01-022A-D</data>
            <data type="quality.assurance">tabtop</data>
            <data type="skill.level">sk01</data>
            <data type="reason.for.update">First Release</data>
            <data type="publication.code">UNKNOWN PUBLICATION</data>
         </data-about>
         <foreign outputclass="issuenum">001</foreign>
         <unknown outputclass="date">2016-01-29</unknown>
      </metadata>
   </prolog>
   <body>
      <section>
         <title>DESCRIPTION</title>
         <p>The A380 is available with two types of turbofan engines, the
Rolls-Royce Trent 900 (variants A380-841, −842 and −843F) or the Engine
Alliance GP7000 (A380-861 and −863F).  Noise reduction was an important
requirement in the A380 design, and particularly affects engine design.</p>
         <p>Landing gears<ul>
               <li>
                  <p>Nose Landing Gear</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Wing Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 4 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <p>Body Landing Gear (Bogie Type, 6 Wheels  - 4 Braked)</p>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </p></section>
         <section>
            <title>Wing Landing Gear</title>

               <p>Each wing landing gear has a leg assembly and
a four-wheel bogie beam. The WLG leg includes a Bogie Trim Actuator
(BTA) and an oleo-pneumatic shock absorber.</p>

         </section>
         <section>
            <title>Body Landing Gear</title>

               <p>The two body landing gears have a six-wheel bogie
beam and a leg assembly that includes an oleo- pneumatic shock absorber.
A two-piece drag-stay assembly mechanically locks the leg in the extended
position.</p>

         </section>

      <section>
         <title>Landing gear</title>
         <image align="center" href="ICN-HSXWB-A-791111-H-F0302-00001-A-001-01.tif"/>
      </section>
   </body>
</topic>
```

Please advice me on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your expected xml is the same as your actual getting output! Please edit it before we can help you out. Please state your xslt processor. XSLT 2 would be appreciated.

Comment: (1) What XSLT processor will you use? Is XSLT 2.0 available? (2) There are (many) Docbook to Dita transformations. With your question you will solve about 1 digit percentage of the real work. My advice: search for `xsl for-each-group group-ending-with` or go with Oxygen and transform it with the embedded full coverage transformation.

Comment: My XSLT version is 2.0. i have downloaded dbdita folder from this link https://sourceforge.net/projects/dita-ot/files/Plug-in_%20dockbook2dita/docbook2dita%201.0/ The dbReader.xsl is acting main part in this. Im converting through the oxygen only. please see that link

Comment: Why dont you simply use this: https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/18/ug-author/topics/docbook-2-dita-transform.html ? This will solve your question as well.

Comment: Yes @uL1. I tried this as per your link. but i'm getting the validation errors with multiple topics as a output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your specific example you can try integrate following template into your XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="section">
    <section>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::section)]"/>
    </section>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="section"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Super. Its working fine. Thanks and one more I want the <section><para> tag want to be as <p> tag in output. can you please guide on this

Comment: Sorry, this is not part of your given, expected output! Please edit your question or close this question by accepting [read this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks @uL1. I will araise that as seperate score